# Javascript location.pathname returns querysting

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to track which page has maximum pagevisits in my site and I am using  location.pathname to return URL but it returns with domain name and querystring/search values.

I do not want domain name and querystring part. Please provide any suggestion to track URL as given below.

Ex: http://example.com/myview/Admin/AdminFirstScreen?activeUser=Abc

Expected result: 
myview/Admin/AdminFirstScreen

Comment: Do you want this in Javascript, Razor view or controller?

Comment: You can use `href` i.e. `location.href.split('?')[0]`

Comment: I want this in Razor view. Inside Script tag I have written this.

Comment: try .`location.hostname;`